# WCF AJAX, jQuery - JSON Data returned is null

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, wcf, web-services

I have come across an error and I hope somebody here can help me as I have been trying to figure out what is wrong for, well, far too long!

Okay I'm using WCF along with AJAX and jQuery to access a class called `Player`

Here's the WCF Interface with the relevant `OperationContract`

```
    [OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        UriTemplate = "/getplayers")]
[return: MessageParameter(Name = "Players")]
Player[] GetPlayersInTeam(int TeamId);
```

Here is the actual Rest Service Method:

```
         public Player[] GetPlayersInTeam(int teamId)
    {
        string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString;

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
        }
        catch
        {

        }

        List<Player> Players = new List<Player>();

        string query = "SELECT * FROM Player WHERE TeamId = @TeamId";

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TeamId", teamId);

        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Player player = new Player(teamId, Convert.ToString(reader[2]), 
                                            Convert.ToString(reader[3]));

                Players.Add(player);
            }

            return Players.ToArray();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Here is the player class:

```
[DataContract(Name = "Player", Namespace = "")]
    public class Player
    {
        // attributes

        private int _teamId;
        private string _playerName;
        private string _position;

        public Player() { }

        public Player(int teamId, string playerName, string position)
        {
            _teamId = teamId;
            _playerName = playerName;
            _position = position;
        }

        [DataMember(Name = "teamId", Order = 1)]
        public int TeamId
        {
            get { return _teamId; }
            set { _teamId = value; }
        }

        [DataMember(Name = "playerName", Order = 2)]
        public string PlayerName
        {
            get { return _playerName; }
            set { _playerName = value; }
        }

        [DataMember(Name = "position", Order = 3)]
        public string Position
        {
            get { return _position; }
            set { _position = value; }
        }
    }
```

And here is the jQuery-Ajax request:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var teamId = $.session.get("teamId");

        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            url: "RestService.svc/getplayers",
            data: '{ "teamId":"' + teamId + '"}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (json, status, req) {
                var JSONReturn = json.Players;

                if (JSONReturn != null) {
                    alert("picked up players");
                }
                else {
                    alert("error");
                }
            },
            error: AjaxError
        });
```

The success function always seems to return `null` and I have no idea why. I basically want to grab all players with the relevant `teamId`, where the `teamId` is a session field. The `teamId` field works just fine and returns the current `teamId` perfectly so it's nothing to do with that.

But anyway, any help would be much appreciated. I just hope its a simple error as I'm going crazy. (Such a noob programmer).

EDIT: The console log function has shown that the json within the success function of the 
ajax request contains the Players list from the Player class but the list is set to null.

```
CONSOLE.LOG
XHR finished loading: "http://localhost:54033/RestService.svc/getplayers". jquery.js:18
send jquery.js:18
b.extend.ajax jquery.js:18
(anonymous function) TeamSelection.aspx:24
c jquery.js:5
p.fireWith jquery.js:5
b.extend.ready jquery.js:5
H jquery.js:5
Object {Players: null}
```

(TeamSelection.aspx anonymous function is the ajax call posted above. AS you can see at the bottom, the json apparently contains an Object called Players, but equal to null.

I can't figure out why this is. I have also added in the dataType but this has not had any effect. I'm stumped :(

Thanks

Comment: do a console.log(json) in your success function and have your console open so you can see the JSON response.  Also set the datatype to json so it will automatically parse your JSON string into a JavaScript object - or do a JSON.parse(json) to get a JavaScript object inside your success function

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try and report back.

Comment: Hi, The console log function has shown that the json contains the Players list from the Player class but the list is set to null. I can't figure out why this is. I have also added in the dataType but this has not had any effect. I'm stumped :(

Comment: can you update your question with your changes?

Comment: Also can you show what the JSON response looks like? don't have to be the whole thing but enough to get the structure

Comment: Sorry but how can I get the JSON response? Do you mean the console.log part?

Comment: Yeah.. the console.log(json).. then copy and paste that response here - if it's an object and you can't copy/paste.. use console.log(JSON.stringify(json))

Comment: hmm.. that's your whole json object?

Comment: Okay after doing the console.log(JSON.stringify(json)) part, all that was returned was: 

{"Players":null}

Comment: unfortunately so I'm afraid. This error has been driving me crazy for the past few hours now. Very strange

Comment: Yeah.. it looks like a server side issue.. Your server response isn't sending anything.  Can you debug on the server - set up break points - and inspect the object to make sure it is actually setting values - stepping through will probably let you pinpoint what's going on

Comment: So there's definitely nothing wrong with the code? If not I'll have to try and debug this server of mine. Not sure how to at the moment though haha. But anyway, thanks for trying! Much appreciated

Comment: Your script looks fine.  It's the JSON response with the value of NULL - that shows it's something on your server side because it's not sending anything to your client.

Comment: Okay well I'll have a try. Thanks again! If you figure anything out let me know :)

Comment: And after 6+ hours or searching a debugging, I have found the error. I only put teamId with a lower case t instead of the upper case T which was needed for it to work with the WCF service. Didn't check for that as I thought it would've thrown an error. 

Well that was a complete waste of my time.. my assignment is due in next Friday. Arghhhhhh (Final uni year madness).

Comment: LOL..  Well I'm glad you figured.  It's always those little mistakes that gives you the biggest headaches